Invalid Token error when using Fernet(Python)
I'm writing a simple encryption/encoding program using base64 and fernet, but when decrypting fernet keeps raising an Invalid Token error.
Here is the code:
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64 as b64,random as rd
def encryt(data):
    key=Fernet.generate_key()
    data=bytes(data,"utf-8")
    key2=rd.randint(0,5)
    for i in range(key2):
        data=b64.a85encode(data)
        data=b64.b32hexencode(data)
    fernet=Fernet(key)
    encrypted=fernet.encrypt(data)
    for i in range(key2):
        encrypted=b64.b32hexencode(encrypted)
        encrypted=b64.a85encode(encrypted)
    for i in range(key2):
        key=b64.b64encode(key)
        key=b64.a85encode(key)
        key=b64.b32hexencode(key)
    final=b64.b85encode(bytes(str(key2),"utf-8")).decode()+"/?\\"+encrypted.decode()+"~`~"+key.decode()
    return(final)
def decrypt(data):
    a=data.split("/?\\")
    key2=int(b64.b85decode(bytes(a[0],"utf-8")))
    b=a[1].split("~`~")
    encrypted=bytes(b[0],"utf-8")
    key=bytes(b[1],"utf-8")
    for i in range(key2):
        key=b64.b32hexdecode(key)
        key=b64.a85decode(key)
        key=b64.b64decode(key)
    fernet=Fernet(key)
    decrypted=fernet.decrypt(encrypted)
    for i in range(key2):
        decrypted=b64.a85decode(decrypted)
        decrypted=b64.b32hexdecode(decrypted)
    return(decrypted.decode())
q="testtes:1234//te"
w=encryt(q)
print(w)
print(decrypt(w))

Hope you guys know how to fix this!
I'm getting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\teech\projects\Wethgan\pyencrypter.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(decrypt(w))
          ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\teech\projects\Wethgan\pyencrypter.py", line 32, in decrypt
    decrypted=fernet.decrypt(encrypted)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 84, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 118, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken

most of the time, but sometimes it just suddenly works.

In decrypt(), all operations regarding decoding and decryption must be performed in reverse order to encryption. This is not the case in your code: Firstly, the decoding of the ciphertext is missing (which you can easily recognize by the fact that there are three for loops in encrypt() but only two in decrypt()). Secondly, there is a bug in the order in which the decrypted data is decoded. If both are fixed, decryption works.

Note that the concatenation of the Fernet key with the ciphertext makes your encryption completely insecure and that multiple binary-to-text encodings do not increase security, but are only inefficient.
